# Stop and Auto Start Program Itself in Python

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, system

Is it possible that my python main thread can stop itself totally and after a time it will restart?

Basically I have an exe written in python which I want to stop but and then again I want to start it after 10-20 minutes without any touch.

Any method to do that?

Comment: use time.sleep()

Comment: perhaps just use the Windows' taskscheduler?